# Matching a string that contains another substring

Tags: java, string

I'm encountering a problem wherein I'm trying to match "***" by using Java's contains() function, but the string contains "*" so it matches the "*", not the "***"

Example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam imperdiet iaculis ex***
```

```
*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
**consectetur adipiscing elit. 
***Aliquam imperdiet iaculis ex
```

I need to concatenate the string by the number of asterisks. So, it must output:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  
consectetur adipiscing elit.   
Aliquam imperdiet iaculis ex***
***Aliquam imperdiet iaculis ex
```

NOT

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Aliquam imperdiet iaculis ex***
*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

I tried using Java's contains() function.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. You can use backquotes for literal text.

Comment: I beg your pardon, but it is not clear to me what your input string is. It looks to me that you have posted two, different input strings. Consequently, I do not understand what you need to do to the input string in order to obtain the output string. It may help me to understand if you posted a [mcve] that includes a sample input string and also shows the output you want to get from that sample input string as well as the output that you actually get.

Answer (score 0):

> *'I'm encountering a problem wherein I'm trying to match "***" by using Java's contains() function, but the string contains "*" so it matches the "*", not the "***" ...'*

The *[String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))* method will attempt to match the exact input; thus a single asterisk will not be matched if you had supplied three.

Here is an example.

```java
System.out.println("*".contains("***"));
```

Output

```
false
```

> *"... I need to concatenate the string by the number of asterisks. ..."*

There are numerous ways to do this.

- You can use the *[StringReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/StringReader.html)* class in conjunction with the *[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html)* class to iterate the *String* value line-for-line.
- Or, you could use the *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class to iterate each line.
- Also, you could use the *[Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)* and *[Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)* classes, utilizing a *regular expression pattern* to evaluate the text.
- Finally, a basic approach would be to use a *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* and a *for-loop*, utilizing the *[String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int))* method to determine the number of asterisks.